# Find parent tag in Grails custom taglib

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, taglib

I am developing custom taglib in Grails which should be aware of parent tag. So if I have something like this in GSP:

```
<a href="#">
  <my:tag blabla="blabla"/>
</a>
```

then implementation of my:tag should be able to find out that it is enclosed inside tag 'a' and not something else.
So is this possible to:
1. Find out which tag is parent?
2. Alter parent tag attributes?

Comment: it's not possible (w/o really ugly and complicated hacks)

Comment: "it's not possible (w/o really ugly and complicated hacks)" - @IgorArtamonov I don't agree with that.  Doing so doesn't require a hack.  You could do it in a simple way with a stack counter that keeps track of when tags are nested inside of other tags.  See my answer below.

Comment: See @IgorArtamonov's comment on my answer below.  I stand corrected.  I misread the question.  I thought you wanted to track when a GSP tag was nested inside of another GSP tag.  That isn't what the question says.  My mistake and I apologize for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT - The answer here does not answer the question as asked.  See the comments for an explanation.  I am going to leave the answer here because deleting it would make all of those other comments incomprehensible, but the answer here is not a valid answer to the question as asked.  I am sorry for the noise.**

There isn't a good way to alter parent tag attributes but that wouldn't be a good idea anyway.  There is almost certainly a better way to accomplish whatever it is that makes you want to do that.  However, wanting to know if a tag is nested in another specific tag is a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do and there are simple ways to do that.  One way is that your parent tag could store some state in `pageScope` and the child tag can interrogate that value to determine if it is being invoked inside of the parent.  You could just use a boolean flag but that would be problematic if you are concerned about multiple levels of nesting.  A counter could keep track of arbitrary depth.

Something like the following should work.

A TagLib:

```
// grails-app/taglib/demo/DemoTagLib.groovy
package demo

class DemoTagLib {

    static namespace = 'demo'

    def someParentTag = { attrs, body ->
        def depthCounter = pageScope.someParentTagDepthCounter ?: 0
        pageScope.someParentTagDepthCounter = ++depthCounter

        out << body()

        pageScope.someParentTagDepthCounter = --depthCounter
    }

    def someChildTag = { attrs, body ->
        // This tag will only render its body if the tag invocation
        // is nested inside of a someParentTag parent.  This just
        // demonstrates one way that a tag can discover if it is
        // nested inside of some other specific tag.
        if(pageScope.someParentTagDepthCounter) {
            out << body()
        }
    }
}
```

A unit test:

```
// src/test/groovy/demo/DemoTagLibSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(DemoTagLib)
class DemoTagLibSpec extends Specification {

    void "test something"() {
        expect: 'when someChildTag is not wrapped in someParentTag then the someChildTag body is not rendered'
        applyTemplate('Heading <demo:someChildTag>Body</demo:someChildTag>') == 'Heading '

        and: 'when someChildTag is wrapped in someParentTag then the someChildTag body is rendered'
        applyTemplate('Heading <demo:someParentTag><demo:someChildTag>Body</demo:someChildTag></demo:someParentTag>') == 'Heading Body'

        and: 'when multiple someChildTags are nested in multiple levels of someParentTags, their bodies are rendered'
        applyTemplate('Heading <demo:someParentTag><demo:someChildTag>First Child<demo:someParentTag> <demo:someChildTag>Second Child</demo:someChildTag></demo:someParentTag></demo:someChildTag></demo:someParentTag>') == 'Heading First Child Second Child'
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: but question was about <a> tag, not custom <demo:someParentTag>. how do you apply that approach to other html tags?

Comment: I see.  You are indeed correct.  I stand corrected.  You could still get there by having your own tag that generates the anchor tag but that isn't what the question was about.  Sorry for the noise.